# Higher resolution not available Ubuntu 14.04 on ESXi host

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, esxi

The maximum resolution available for my Ubuntu 14.04 vm is 1360x768.  However, the max resolution for my Ubuntu 16.04 is 2560x1600.  Both are running on the same ESXi host with the same video card settings.  Both have the latest version of VMware tools installed.

The physical monitor I am accessing from is 2560x1600.

### Ubuntu 14.04

[image: Ubuntu 14.04]

### Ubuntu 16.04

[image: Ubuntu 16.04]

The video card settings for both VMs looks like this.  The video card has plenty of memory.
[image]

**Ubuntu 14.04**

```
ubuntu2@ubuntu2-virtual-machine:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
ubuntu2@ubuntu2-virtual-machine:~$ find /dev -group video
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/renderD128
/dev/dri/controlD64
/dev/agpgart
ubuntu2@ubuntu2-virtual-machine:~$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
```

**Ubuntu 16.04**

```
root@ubuntu3-virtual-machine:/home/ubuntu3# lspci | grep VGA
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
root@ubuntu3-virtual-machine:/home/ubuntu3# find /dev -group video
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/renderD128
/dev/dri/controlD64
root@ubuntu3-virtual-machine:/home/ubuntu3# glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
```

Why does 14.04 not offer a higher resolution, and how can I make it do so?

Comment: Did you verify they use the same X driver?

Comment: `lspci | grep VGA` returns `00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter` for both VMs

Comment: Yes of course. That’s just a list of PCI devices, however. It doesn’t tell you what driver is in use, if any. See [these answers](http://askubuntu.com/q/28033).

Comment: I edited my question to provide that additional info.